# Using partial derivatives in mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, formatting

I am attempting to use the partial derivative operator in mathematica but can't quite get it working. This is my code.

```
Subscript[\[PartialD],x]x
```

It keeps saying "Derivative: ∂, x cannot be interpreted. A partial derivative requires a subscript differentiation variable."

Is this not how you do it? I have looked at a lot of documentation ... Also I do not want to use D[x,y] (more friendly for my code)

Comment: Your issue is that the box-structure is wrong. You will want something like this: ``ToExpression[
 RowBox[{SubscriptBox["\[PartialD]", RowBox[{"x"}]], 
   "y"}], StandardForm, Defer]``. Mathematica has a front-end that works with "boxes". This is a case where your "boxes" aren't quite right for it to interpret.

Comment: "Also I do not want to use D[x,y] (more friendly for my code)"  Mathematica is a programming language. You *should* use clear and unambiguous code.  Traditional mathematical notation is far from unambiguous.

Comment: But if you really want to, you can type the following sequence of keys: ESC pd ESC Ctrl-_ x RightArrow x.  This is *not* the same as what you show in your post, even though it *looks* the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> and fill in the blanks is one way.  In the subscript you can put as many variables as you want, separated by <kbd>,</kbd>.

Comment: Your using a version that does not allow escape key commands?

Comment: backslash[PartialD] ctrl- also works

Comment: the partial clearly shows up in the notebook but I can't seem to add the subscripts on as shown in the code above ...

Comment: The control- (control-minus sign) isn't working for you?  That is how I create a subscript.

Comment: If you have access to it, the Basic Math Assistant Pallete has it.